# Webview with JavascriptInterface and a call with argument type "function"

Tags: javascript, java, android, android-webview

I have implemented a `JavascriptInterface` on a `Webview` that creates an object **comNative**.

"**comNative**" has a slow commands and I want to run a javascript callback when it ends.

That callback has been defined on javascript argument. Sample codes:

**JavaScript**

```
comNative.slowNativeMethod(function() { alert('Yaw!'); });
```

**ANDROID**

```
public void slowNativeMethod(string callback) {
        <slow things>...

        webview.evaluateJavascript("new" + callback + "();", null);
    }
```

The problem is that this argument is not a javascript "string" type, it's a "function" type and arrives to native method as "undefined" string.

For workaround I can define the callback argument as string like "`comNative.slowNativeMethod(function() { alert('Yaw!'); }.toString());`".

But I want to avoid this.

**Do you have any idea to solve it or is that a limitation of JavaScriptInterface?**

Thanks!!